# How to avoid duplicates with hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

This relates a bit to my last [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964508/how-to-get-the-path-of-an-hierarchy-table)

Anyway, I have an hierarchical table structured as follow(In real, the codes will always be varchar2(3), the numbers are only to simplify):

```
Family_code  |   Parent_Family_Code  | ....
    1                   2
    2                   4
    3                   6
    4                   3
    6                   null
    8                   null
    9                   8
   ......................
```

Output should be:

```
Family_code | parent_1 | p_2 | p_3 | p_4 | p_5 | .....
      1          2        4     3     6     null    null.....
      2          4        3     6     null   null...
      3          6        null...
      4          3        6     null ...
      6          null...
      8          null...
      9          8        null..
```

I've come up with a solution using `connect by` `substr()` and `connect_by_path` ,  which result in the expected output, but with duplicates - not exactly duplicate, but lets say family_code = 1 produce the results `(1,2,4,3,6,null..)` and `(1,2,4,3,null,null...)` and `(1,2,4,null...)` instead of only (1,2,4,3,6,null...) which is the full path. This is the query:

```
SELECT s.family_code,
 s.parent_family_code_1,
 s.parent_family_code_2,
 CASE WHEN length(s.family_path) - (4 * 3 + 2) > 0 THEN substr(s.family_path, length(s.family_path) - (4 * 3 + 2), 3) ELSE NULL END as parent_family_code_3,
 CASE WHEN length(s.family_path) - (4 * 4 + 2) > 0 THEN substr(s.family_path, length(s.family_path) - (4 * 4 + 2), 3) ELSE NULL END as parent_family_code_4,
 CASE WHEN length(s.family_path) - (4 * 5 + 2) > 0 THEN substr(s.family_path, length(s.family_path) - (4 * 5 + 2), 3) ELSE NULL END as parent_family_code_5,
 CASE WHEN length(s.family_path) - (4 * 6 + 2) > 0 THEN substr(s.family_path, length(s.family_path) - (4 * 6 + 2), 3) ELSE NULL END as parent_family_code_6,
 CASE WHEN length(s.family_path) - (4 * 7 + 2) > 0 THEN substr(s.family_path, length(s.family_path) - (4 * 7 + 2), 3) ELSE NULL END as parent_family_code_7,
 CASE WHEN length(s.family_path) - (4 * 8 + 2) > 0 THEN substr(s.family_path, length(s.family_path) - (4 * 8 + 2), 3) ELSE NULL END as parent_family_code_8,
 CASE WHEN length(s.family_path) - (4 * 9 + 2) > 0 THEN substr(s.family_path, length(s.family_path) - (4 * 9 + 2), 3) ELSE NULL END as parent_family_code_9,
 CASE WHEN length(s.family_path) - (4 * 10 + 2) > 0 THEN substr(s.family_path, length(s.family_path) - (4 * 10 + 2), 3) ELSE NULL END as parent_family_code_10
  FROM (SELECT t.family_code,
               t.parent_family_code as parent_family_code_1,
               prior t.parent_family_code as parent_family_code_2,
               sys_connect_by_path(t.family_code, ',') as family_path
          FROM table t
        connect by prior t.family_code = t.parent_family_code) s
```

I can use a sub query to fix that by comparing the maximum length of the path and taking only it:

```
SELECT * FROM (        
SELECT t.family_code,
               t.parent_family_code as parent_family_code_1,
               prior t.parent_family_code as parent_family_code_2,
               sys_connect_by_path(t.family_code, ',') as family_path
          FROM WIZ_PRODUCT_FAMILY_CODES t
        connect by prior t.family_code = t.parent_family_code) t  
        WHERE length(t.family_path) =  (SELECT MAX(length(sys_connect_by_path(s.family_code, ','))) FROM WIZ_PRODUCT_FAMILY_CODES s
                                        where s.family_code = t.family_code
                                        connect by prior s.family_code = s.parent_family_code)
```

But then it become ugly and messy and will be difficult to do maintaince on it when other programmer will try to work on it.

So, is there a better/more readable way taking only the **full** path record ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no `START WITH` clause in you hierarchical query. This clause determines records that are root nodes of hierarchies in your table. Without this clause all records in the thable are treated as root nodes, and Oracle takes each records one after another as "root", and for each one generates a hierarchy. For example if you have 1-2-3-4, then without `START WITH col=1` you will get in total 4 hierarchies: 1-2-3-4, 2-3-4, 3-4 and 4. Check out my last answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964508/how-to-get-the-path-of-an-hierarchy-table - there is `START WITH ` clause there.

Comment: Thats basically what I want, I want the path for each record in the table, not just for the roots of the hierarchy(look at my output example), but I want only the entire path of each one of them.. @kordirko . And although I accepted your answer in the last question, it didn't provide the correct result, I just wanted another approach the substring..

Comment: It's hard to diagnose without looking at data in the table. Please create a minimal verifable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve of input data in the table (only few records would be enought), together with actual result generated by the query, and the desiderd result for this example data.

Comment: @kordirko I've updated the question with data and the exact output I expect from it. The query return the expected output but with extras, take family_code = 4 for example. It will be returned as this combinations : `(4,3,6,null..)` , `(4,3,null...)` , `(4,null,null.....)` instead of only `(4,3,6,null...)` which is the entire path of `4`

Answer (score 0):

Take [my answer from your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36964715/1509264) and comment out the `WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1` filter...

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Family_code, Parent_Family_Code ) AS
SELECT  1,    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2,    4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3,    6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4,    3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4,    5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9,    8 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( path, '/(\d+)', 1, max_depth, NULL, 1 ) ) AS family_code,
       CASE WHEN max_depth >  1 THEN TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( path, '/(\d+)', 1, max_depth -  1, NULL, 1 ) ) END AS p1,
       CASE WHEN max_depth >  2 THEN TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( path, '/(\d+)', 1, max_depth -  2, NULL, 1 ) ) END AS p2,
       CASE WHEN max_depth >  3 THEN TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( path, '/(\d+)', 1, max_depth -  3, NULL, 1 ) ) END AS p3,
       CASE WHEN max_depth >  4 THEN TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( path, '/(\d+)', 1, max_depth -  4, NULL, 1 ) ) END AS p4,
       CASE WHEN max_depth >  5 THEN TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( path, '/(\d+)', 1, max_depth -  5, NULL, 1 ) ) END AS p5,
       CASE WHEN max_depth >  6 THEN TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( path, '/(\d+)', 1, max_depth -  6, NULL, 1 ) ) END AS p6,
       CASE WHEN max_depth >  7 THEN TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( path, '/(\d+)', 1, max_depth -  7, NULL, 1 ) ) END AS p7,
       CASE WHEN max_depth >  8 THEN TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( path, '/(\d+)', 1, max_depth -  8, NULL, 1 ) ) END AS p8,
       CASE WHEN max_depth >  9 THEN TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( path, '/(\d+)', 1, max_depth -  9, NULL, 1 ) ) END AS p9,
       CASE WHEN max_depth > 10 THEN TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( path, '/(\d+)', 1, max_depth - 10, NULL, 1 ) ) END AS p10
FROM   (
  SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( Family_code, '/' ) AS path,
         LEVEL AS max_depth
  FROM   table_name
  --WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
  CONNECT BY PRIOR Family_Code = Parent_Family_Code
  START WITH Parent_Family_Code IS NULL
);
```

**Output**:

```
FAMILY_CODE         P1         P2         P3         P4         P5         P6         P7         P8         P9        P10
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
          5                                                                                                               
          4          5                                                                                                    
          2          4          5                                                                                         
          1          2          4          5                                                                              
          6                                                                                                               
          3          6                                                                                                    
          4          3          6                                                                                         
          2          4          3          6                                                                              
          1          2          4          3          6                                                                   
          8                                                                                                               
          9          8
```